# mac c++ compiler not finding <tr1/unordered_map>

Tags: c++, macos

I guess the question of the day is "which" c++ compiler is the default on mac?

If I do `xcrun -find c++` it says it's in `/Applications/Xcode.app/etc...`.

When I search the Xcode directory for `tr1/unordered_map`, it's there.

So I'm confused.  Why am I getting a build error that says `fatal error: 'tr1/unordered_map' file not found`?

Comment: Don't know about macs, but `tr1` shouts "old compiler".

Comment: "it's there" -> where exactly?

Comment: What command did you run in order to compile? Or are you inside XCode GUI?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I didn't write this particular piece of code; but I'm stuck with it ;-).  Can I just grab the code and put it somewhere and do a cmake option like -I /path/to/thing and it would work?

Comment: @ForceBru, good question.  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/unordered_map` and 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/unordered_map`

Comment: @ForceBru I also have gcc on the system.  `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/include/c++/6.2.0/tr1/unordered_map` and 
`/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/include/c++/6.2.0/tr1/unordered_map.h`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm not using Xcode GUI.  I prefer CLion.

Comment: So, if you want to use that, you need to tell CLion to use `/usr/local/bin/g++-6`

Comment: @MarkSetchell ok cool.  The way to do that is to set cmake options `-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++-6 -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-6`.  And it still didn't work.  `fatal error: 'tr1/unordered_map' file not found`.

Comment: What standard are you trying to compile to? If `-std=c++11`, then you must lose the `tr1` part.

Comment: `-std=c99`.  What I had to do was reference the includes and the libs (which happen to be in the same place) `-I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/include/c++/6.2.0/tr1/ -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/include/c++/6.2.0/tr1/`.  But now I have a gaggle of errors pertaining to `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to look in the directory where you have pointed `-L`, find some libraries and add their names with `-l`

Comment: @Bear You can't use C++ headers if you're explicitly telling your compiler to compile C.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Short answer:** call clang++ with `-stdlib=libstdc++`, and the `tr1` headers will be there.

**Long answer:**
The reason for your error and the 2 sets of C++ includes is that macOS/Xcode has two different C++ standard libraries you can build against: an old GNU `libstdc++`, and the new and modern LLVM `libc++`.

As of macOS 10.12 Sierra, the default is now `libc++` and `libstdc++` is deprecated. `libstdc++` is quite old, v4.2.1, and predates C++11 (hence the `tr1` headers). If you're going to be using this code long-term, it'd be worth the time to at least make it C++11 compliant (i.e. `#include <unordered_map>`)

**Update**: Xcode 10 no longer allows building against libstdc++. Either update your codebase to use standard C++11 headers, or use Xcode 9 if that's really not an option.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but how do I set this in xcode?

Comment: Sorry, not sure exactly what the build setting is called. `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` is the name of the variable. Note that Xcode 10 and up don't support libstdc++ though.