# BNA Archive file creation fails on mac

Tags: node.js, macos, hyperledger

I started with the composer-sample-network and created my-network as per the developer tools tutorials. When I am trying to create the .bna file on my mac it fails.In file included from

```
../src/hashtable.cpp:1:
../src/hashtable.h:7:10: fatal error: 'tr1/unordered_map' file not 
found
#include <tr1/unordered_map
```

I am running node version 7.5.0
    npm version 5.3.0
    mac OS - Sierra 10.12.0
    python 2.7.13

Comment: This answer should cover what you are experiencing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42034101/4351210

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mac c++ compiler not finding <tr1/unordered\_map>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030598/mac-c-compiler-not-finding-tr1-unordered-map)

Comment: Ven Kumar, can u accept and close this question?

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade your node version to 6 and reinstall your hyperledger env.
**Node version 7 or 8 are not supported.**

```
npm install -g n
sudo n 6.10.0
...
npm install -g composer-cli (might be some)
```

Comment: This is exactly the correct answer and should have been marked as such.